# Socket.io can't connect on mobile browser even with wifi on

Tags: javascript, websocket, socket.io, socket.io-1.0

to try socket.io, I coded a simple chat which works well on every pc. However, on mobile (I tried on my iphone 4S and an Ipad) even if the html is running well, it looks like the connect line `let socket = io();`  doesn't work, so nothing is working from socket.io. I saw online that it was working on wifi but it doesn't work either. I also saw that running the server on port 433 could help but socket io still doesn't connect(it works well for everyone who is on PC).

Any idea why and how to correct that ? I do want to target mobile browser for my app.

Here's my client code : [deleted]

EDIT : it does the same on android, while PC does an awesome job at running it.
EDIT2 : I just debbugged on mobile with android, it throws a "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier" on the "let socket = io();" line

Why ?

Comment: That sounds like you either aren't running a new enough browser to support `let` or you haven't loaded the socket.io library before you try to use it.

Answer (score 0):

Going to need a lot more information than that to give a useful response.

A snippet of your socket io server call would suffice.

From what I can gather I believe that you must be running your socket server locally on your machine not using a web server. So I believe you will either need to open up the port you're attempting to connect to with your mobile device, or make sure you're targeting the correct internal IP address of the machine you are running the socket server from.

Comment: I am running a web server ! There is no port problem since I can see my web page from everywhere ! All ports needed are open on my AWS instance, so I don't know why it doesn't work on mobile browser.

Comment: Could you edit your question and add in your server / web server / code / as this issue could be anything from a local port issue ( as a socket server is different from you just being able to access the page ) down to a code problem. Lacking that I will be unable to help.